Sum a Column of a Timeseries by an Order Number when the Ordernumber is not unique
I have a table production like this.



id [PK integer]
order_id [integer]
start [timestamp]
end [timestamp]
count [integer]




1
1
10:00
11:00
15


2
1
11:00
12:00
1


3
2
12:00
13:00
2


4
3
13:00
14:00
10


5
1
14:00
15:00
4


6
1
15:00
16:00
7


7
1
16:00
17:00
3


8
3
17:00
18:00
21


9
1
18:00
19:00
5



The result I like to get:



order_id
start
end
count




1
10:00
12:00
16


2
12:00
13:00
2


3
13:00
14:00
10


1
14:00
17:00
14


3
17:00
18:00
21


1
18:00
19:00
5



Last thing I tried:
WITH lp AS (
    SELECT *,LEAD(order_id) OVER(ORDER BY start) AS next_id
    FROM production
)
SELECT order_id,
    MIN(start) AS start,
    MAX(end) AS end,
    SUM(count) AS count
   FROM lp
    WHERE order_id = next_id
  GROUP BY order_id
  ORDER BY MIN(start);

I know that the query is incorrect. How to include the first line of the table
Any ideas how to fix ?
Thank's a lot for the help.

Try use gaps and islands methods.

What is desired output if gap in time (id,order_id,start,end):(1,100,'10:00', '11:00', 5),(2,100,'12:00', '13:00', 6)? (100,'10:00', '13:00', 11)?


You can get current order_id and the previous one using LAG which is part of ordered_data CTE.
And then create a new group every time a new order is found, otherwise contiguous block of the same order_id gets a unique grp value in grouped_data CTE
In final select based on order_id and grp , get the sum of count

Fiddle
WITH ordered_data AS (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        order_id, 
        start, 
        end1, 
        count,
        LAG(order_id) OVER (ORDER BY start) AS prev_order_id
    FROM test
),
grouped_data AS (
    SELECT 
        id,
        order_id, 
        start, 
        end1, 
        count,
        SUM(CASE WHEN order_id = prev_order_id THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY start) AS grp
    FROM ordered_data
)
SELECT 
    order_id,
    MIN(start) AS start,
    MAX(end1) AS end1,
    SUM(count) AS count
FROM grouped_data
GROUP BY order_id, grp
ORDER BY MIN(start);




order_id
start
end1
count




1
2023-12-19 10:00:00
2023-12-19 12:00:00
16


2
2023-12-19 12:00:00
2023-12-19 13:00:00
2


3
2023-12-19 13:00:00
2023-12-19 14:00:00
10


1
2023-12-19 14:00:00
2023-12-19 17:00:00
14


3
2023-12-19 17:00:00
2023-12-19 18:00:00
21


1
2023-12-19 18:00:00
2023-12-19 19:00:00
5




Moin, thank you so much . It works perfect!

Thank you! If you found it helpful you can upvote and accept as answer:)
